# Change value of hidden field didn't work

Tags: jquery

A simple question with (i assumed) a simple solution, but why *won't* the following (stripped down version with the lines that matters) work:

**EDIT:**
I edited my example code a bit so it maybe makes it more clear why it has the error

I'm still doubting about the code because it seems ugly and there's a lot of unuseful stuff in there, but i didn't get to the optimization phase

HTML:

```
   <div class="select-container">
   <input type="hidden" name="enroll-persons-field" id="enroll-persons-field">
   <select size="1" name="enroll-persons" id="enroll-persons" class="form-options" tabindex="7">
   <option value=""></option>
      <optgroup label="Ik boek voor">
         <option value="1" selected>1 persoon&lt;/option>
         <option value="2">2 personen&lt;/option>
         <option value="3">3 personen&lt;/option>
         <option value="4">4 personen&lt;/option>
         <option value="5">5 personen&lt;/option>
         <option value="more">meer dan 5 personen&lt;/option>
      </optgroup>
   <select>
<div>

[..]

<input type="text" name="enroll-address" id="enroll-address" class="default-input-style" placeholder="Je adres" tabindex="10" required>
```

Now I'm replacing the select list via jQuery to style the option list. I can imagine its an ugly approach but so far it works

```
$(".select-container").after("&lt;div class='select-list-container'>&lt;/div>");
$(".select-list-container").append("&lt;ul id='select-option-list'>");
$(".form-options option").each(function(){
   li = '&lt;li id="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).attr('text')+'&lt;/li>';
   $("#select-option-list").append(li);
});
$(".select-list-container").append("&lt;/ul>");
$(".form-options").hide();
$(".select-container").text($(".form-options option:last").attr('text')).click(function(){
   $(".select-list-container").toggle("fast");
});
$("#select-option-list li").live("click", function(){
   $(".select-container").text($(this).text());
   $(".select-list-container").toggle("fast");
   $("#enroll-persons-field").val($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Hope this description will help

The `alert()` gives `undefined` as a result and `$(this).attr('id')` is a legit value.  I tested it :)

**EDIT2:**
Solved it by placing the hidden input field outside the `select-container div`

Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: only reason by which it couldn't work from my pov is if the hidden element is added dynamically and/or not in the DOMs scope when the script that assigns the value executes... say if the hidden field, *enroll-persons-field* has a default value are you able to get that value by alert?

Comment: The hidden field is presented just in the html. When i give it an value, the alert() still return undefined

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `$(this).attr('id')` is ran in the context of the document, which doesn't have an attribute called ID. Change that to `$("#enroll-persons-field").attr("id")`, or store the result in a variable and use it twice.

Comment: `this == window // returns false`

Comment: @gilly3: It seems the context is `document` instead of `window`. I didn't know jQuery passes that as the context, and I assumed window because that's what the default context is. It's all the same though, since neither is correct here.

Comment: I edited my post with the full code, it does have an attribute id, because i defined that earlier, or am i loosing it?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - Right. The `document` context is used because `$(function() {})` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.  So it is handling an event on the `document`, and is thus executed in the context of the `document`.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted, `this` is `document`.  And `$(this).attr("id")` is equivalent to `document.id`.  Unless you previously set `document.id` somewhere in JavaScript, that value will be undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpuGh/

You'll need to get a reference to whatever you expected `this` to be, and use that instead.

---

By the way, `$(this).attr("id")` is the same as `this.id`.  There's no sense invoking the overhead of jQuery here.

Comment: I always assumed that $(this) applied to the element that is triggered, in this case (see edited code) the list item that is clicked

Comment: @Maurice - Indeed.  Your original code had `$(this)` inside the document ready handler, whose context is, of course, the document.  In your updated code `$(this)` represents the option element and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$("input#enroll-persons-field").val($(this).attr('id'));
```

to

```
var text = $("input#enroll-persons-field").attr('id');
$("input#enroll-persons-field").val(text);
```

If you want to keep what you had, you could always:

```
var this = $("input#enroll-persons-field");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="enroll-persons-field" value="myvalue" id="enroll-persons-field">
```

`value` is value, `id` is id.

Answer (score 0):

In short your

```
$("input#enroll-persons-field").val($(this).attr('id'));
```

Like gilly3 pointed out, doesn't refer to the ID you want.

```
$("input#enroll-persons-field").val( function(){ return $(this).attr('id') });
```

Will do what you expect since this attr('id') refers to your "#enroll-persons-field" instead of the document itself.

Comment: odd, It was tested, with this revised, the answers so far are irrelevant though.